# retrieving pdf(file) from database in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am able to successfully store uploaded pdf in database using binary datatype in database. Now i want to retrieve that pdf and store in variable something like mypdf = xxx.pdf , so that i can pass that pdf in few of my methods. I want to do in ruby or rails.

let me rephrase what i mean. i want to retrieve pdf file which is already stored in database. i know for eg this code in controller will render pdf locally.  send_data @attachment.data, :filename => @attachment.filename, :type => @attachment.content_type  but i don't want to show the pdf. i want to assign the pdf to variable and later on pass that pdf to my method

Thanks for help

Comment: Moreover you can register the Mime type of PDF and retrieve it easily...

Comment: @AnandKumar do you want to send the PDF or display pdf online

Answer (score 0):

Use prawn gem and you can see the railscasts episode for it...
http://railscasts.com/episodes/153-pdfs-with-prawn

Comment: I guess not what he want perhaps he can do it without prawn as he saying the pdf is already in database